# Adding matrices

Tags: java, matrix, mathematics

This is what the code should do:

> Check if the first dimensions and the second dimensions of each 2-dimensionalarray are the same. If they are not the same, then return a 0x0 2-dimensional array. array, otherwise do the following;
>
> - Allocate memory for a local 2-dim. array with the same dimensions as one of the 2-dim. array parameters
> - Add each corresponding element in the parameter 2-dim. arrays and store the result in the corresponding element ofthe local 2-dim. array (use nested for loops)
> - Return the local 2-dim. array

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Homework2 {
public static void main(String[] args){

   int d1 = (int) (Math.random()*(10-3+1)+3);
   int d2 = (int) (Math.random()*(10-3+1)+3);

   double[][] doubMatrix1 = new double[d1][d2];
   double[][] doubMatrix2 = new double[d1][d2];
   double[][] doubMatrix3 = new double[d1][d2];

   doubMatrix1 = getdoubMatrix(d1,d2);
   doubMatrix2 = getdoubMatrix(d1,d2);
   doubMatrix3 = addMatrices(doubMatrix1, doubMatrix2);
}
  public static double[][] getdoubMatrix(int d1, int d2){

   double[][] tempArray = new double[d1][d2];

   for(int i =0; i <tempArray.length;i++ )
      for(int j =0;j < tempArray[i].length;j++)
           tempArray[i][j] = Math.random()*(10.0);

   return  tempArray;
}
public static double[][] addMatrices(double doubMatrix1[][], double doubMatrix2[][]){

   double[][] tempArray = null;
   int i,j = 0;
   for(i = 0; i< doubMatrix1.length;i++)
       for(j = 0; j< doubMatrix1[i].length;j++ )
       {
           if(doubMatrix1[i][j] == doubMatrix2[i][j])
           {
               tempArray = new double[i][j];
               tempArray[i][j] = doubMatrix1[i][j] + doubMatrix2[i][j];
           }
           else
           {
               return tempArray = new double[0][0];

           }
       }

   return tempArray;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably should reread the specifications.   “Check if the first dimensions and the second dimensions of each 2-dim. array array are the same” means that you should check if first and second matrix lengths match; it does *not* mean to test `doubMatrix1[i][j] == doubMatrix2[i][j]`.  Also test sizes of `doubMatrix1[0]` and  `doubMatrix2[0]`; ie besides testing `doubMatrix1.length` vs `doubMatrix2.length`, test `doubMatrix1[0].length` vs `doubMatrix2[0].length`.  If the sizes don't match, then do your `return tempArray = new double[0][0];` statement, or perhaps `return new double[0][0];`.  That particular statement should be before, not inside, the nested for loops.

“Add each corresponding element in the parameter 2-dim. arrays and store the result” means to do something like your
`tempArray[i][j] = doubMatrix1[i][j] + doubMatrix2[i][j];`
statement.  However, your code repeatedly reallocates `tempArray[][]`, so `tempArray[][]` never has more than one element set in it.  Allocate the array earlier in your program, perhaps after you know the sizes match.

Answer (score 5):

This is Java, not C-before-C99.  You can declare your variables in the loop statement, rather than before the loop statement:

> ```
> int i,j = 0;
> for(i = 0; i< doubMatrix1.length;i++)
>     for(j = 0; j< doubMatrix1[i].length;j++ )
> ```

Change that to:

```
for(int i = 0; i< doubMatrix1.length;i++)
    for(int j = 0; j< doubMatrix1[i].length;j++ )
```

The first statement is entirely redundant as you never use them outside the scope of the loop.

---

You should format your code better.  `j< doubMatrix1[i].length;j++ )` is messy, and should read as `j < doubMatrix1[i].length; j++)`

---

Your indentation is messy too.  Mainly, you should be consistent, and 4 spaces is the typical Java standard.  This, for example, is difficult to read and see the scope automatically:

> ```
> }
>   public static double[][] getdoubMatrix(int d1, int d2){
> ```

---

> ```
> int i,j = 0;
> ```

That assignment only assigns `j`, `i` is unassigned.  As I mentioned earlier, these are redundant anyway, but you should know about this behavior.  If you want `i` assigned too, you have to do `int i = 0, j = 0;`.

Comment: _This is Java, not C. You can declare your variables in the loop statement, rather than before the loop statement:_ <- you can in C99 too